# How to check what is running in a server?

Tags: linux

1. Is there any particular command to find out what servers (like: apache2, mysql-server, backup-server etc) are running inside a dedicated server?
2. If I will reboot my dedicated server will they all start automatically?
3. What is the safe way of reboot a dedicated server with all its applications server running inside it?

Note: I am in a dedicated Debian server.

Comment: "curl -I *your-URL*" will give you the output as, on which server the application s running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that application servers are using ports [Apache, Mysql do]
If so you can use `netstat -lepunt` to find out the services running in your server.

If you want to know the services are started at boot time check for init scripts in `/etc/init.d/`.

Most of the time services like Apache and MySQL servers are started at boot time if they are installed using a package manager. If not you can create an init script to start them at the boot time.

Comment: Please let me know the command with extension to safely `reboot` the dedicated server.

Comment: to reboot gracefully: `shutdown -r now`

Answer (score 5):

`ps aux` will also list all the processes running on the server. You can look for the related services there.

Answer (score 2):

`htop` gives a nice overview of the processes that are running and the resources that are in use.

Answer (score 0):

Try these to see servers listening on TCP/UDP ports. I like it to have an overview of a server's purpose.

```
netstat -lepunt | perl -nle 's!^.*\d+/!! && print if ($_);' | sort -u
```

or

```
ss -tualp | perl -nle 's/^.*users:.."(.*?)".*/$1/ && print;' | sort -u
```

Then you might want to also check the content of `/etc/crontab` to see what else the machine is doing (like backups for example).

And if running Apache, something like this may be useful:

```
grep -h -i ServerName /etc/apache2/{sites,conf}-enabled/* | grep -v '^\s*#'
```